# Adobe Reader X (10.0) ActiveX: annotations are disabled

Tags: activex, adobe-reader

I just embedded Adobe Reader X ActiveX control in a small sample applications. All controls related to Annotations and Comments are disabled.

Why is that? Can I enable them via code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior seems to be intensionally and can't be changed.
The answer from Adobe can be found here: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/757876

Answer (score -1):

My case was simple, uninstalled and installed the latest version and the same pdf file was open to be annotated.