# Using Adobe plugin in WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, adobe, acrobat-sdk

I have been trying to enable commenting in Adobe plugin in a c# WinForm, but I couldn't find a way. I even started a bounty on another question, but I didn't get any help ([Enabling annotation in Adobe AxAcroPDFLib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019736/enabling-annotation-in-adobe-axacropdflib)).

So I wonder if it is possible to use the browser plugin version in a WebBrowser control in a C# WinForm.
If so, can I then use Javascript with this plugin, for example:

```
Collab.showAnnotToolsWhenNoCollab = True
```

Please provide sample code if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably going to be using PDFium for that https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pdfium.Net.SDK/ .

There are a number of .NET viewers like this built around the PDFium binaries, https://www.nuget.org/packages/PdfiumViewer/ .