# Highlight text of PDF--same functionality as Adobe?

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf, pdf

I have an `Acro COM` object on a `WCF`. the document loads correctly and most of the functionality you get through Adobe can be found within the COM. I need the "Comment" toolbar (specifically the "Highlight Text" tool) to be active. I can open that toolbar, but every option is greyed out. This may be a duplicate, but I haven't been able to find an answer to this question specifically despite searching everything I could find.

I do not need to save the highlighted text when I close the PDF. My PDF loading code is:

```
   Private Sub LOMCDataEntry_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim screen As Screen
    screen = screen.AllScreens(0)
    frmPDF.Bounds = (From scr In screen.AllScreens Where Not scr.Primary)(1).WorkingArea
    frmPDF.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
    frmPDF.AxAcroPDF1.LoadFile("G:\GIS\Alycia\Development\LOMCDev\2015084\Regular LOMC Section\Region I\NH\15-01-0961A-330104.pdf")
    frmPDF.Show()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Javascript:

```
collab.showAnnotToolsWhenNoCollab = true
```

Take a look at this question:
[Enabling annotation in Adobe AxAcroPDFLib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019736/enabling-annotation-in-adobe-axacropdflib)
It's for C# but it may help.

Also download the SDK (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat.html) and check the ActiveViewVB sample project.